Handling Complex Authentication Scenarios in a Microservices-based System
I am building my first microservices-based system and I have a couple of things that I can't wrap my head around them. Before that, let me briefly talk about the application just to give you guys some context.
System Description
The system is divided into many modules, for example, we have a Project module to manage projects, tasks, subtasks, etc. Another module would be the Library module, which handles files, folders, uploading files, downloading them, etc.
We have another important module that handles users in the system. Additionally, the module also is responsible for handling departments. In a nutshell, this module handles the crud of users, the crud of departments, and also user-department associations (for instance, add user A to department B or make user B the manager of department c). It is worth mentioning that departments are hierarchical; i.e., a department can have one parent department.
The Microservice Architecture
The way we are planning to set it up as a microservices-based system is as follows:

We will have a Gateway microservice; this microservice will be
the only publicly accessible microservice, and accessing any of the
internal microservices has to go through the Gateway microservice.
We will have an Identity microservice; the microservice will handle
the user's crud, departments' crud, user-department associations, and
authenticating users with JWT generation.
Authentication and authorization will be managed by each microservice
based on the JWT token.
Each other module (e.g., Project module) will be its own
microservice.

The Challenge
The issue we have has to do with complex authorization scenarios. Simple authorization, like user A has to have permission B, is simple as we are going to include all permissions for a user in the JWT token. However, more complicated ones are a bit tricky.
For context, here's an example: Let's say that in the Project microservice, a user creates Project A. And let us say that Project A is assigned to Department B. Let us also assume that for a project to be active, it has to go through a series of approvals as follows:

Step 1: Project A has to be approved by Department B's manager.
Step 2: Project A has to be approved by Department B's parent
department's (Department C) manager.
Step 3: Project A has to be approved by Department C's parent
department's manager.
Step 4: Project A has to be approved by a user with Permission D to
be active.

It is worth noting that for Step 1 if Department B does not have a manager, the system should go up a level and check if there is a manager and forward the request to them. Similarly in Steps 2 and 3, if there were no immediate parent departments, then the system should look up the hierarchy until it finds the closest department with a manager and forward the request to them. If no managers were found, then the request should go immediately to Step 4.
Now, this logic is very easy to implement in a monolith system (we already did it before). However, the challenge here is that the Project microservice does not have the necessary information (basically user-department associations) to figure out this flow (the information it needs is hosted in the Identity microservice).
The only solution that I can think of here is to replicate the users/departments/user-department-associates into all other microservices (the Project microservice is not the only one with this problem). Also, we do not want to introduce any synchronous communications between microservices to reduce coupling between them. Is this a sound solution? Or are there other better approaches to handle this?


The issue we have has to do with complex authorization scenarios. Simple authorization, like user A has to have permission B, is simple as we are going to include all permissions for a user in the JWT token. However, more complicated ones are a bit tricky.

Based on this, your problem looks like a perfect candidate for ReBAC. The idea being a central microservice that returns authorization decisions.
There are a couple of solutions in the market that implement this approach, both open source and commercial.
Disclaimer: i am currently part of the team that is building one such solution.
